# mysql query where = value could exist or could not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hello I have a problem regarding a MySQL query.

The following query is what I want to get a result.

However, one the `thumb_file` column in the `color_all` table could have data or be `NULL`.

```
    $query =  "SELECT DISTINCT(p.location), p.no, c.thumb_file FROM product_pics AS p, color_all AS c 
                WHERE style_number = '$style' AND p.color = c.color ORDER BY p.sort ASC";
```

Actually, I can make this query like the following 2 queries:

```
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT(location), no, color FROM product_pics WHERE style_number = '$style' ORDER BY ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while(list($loc, $no, $color) = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $sub_query = "SELECT thumb_file FROM color_all WHERE color = '$color'";
    }
```

But I just want to know how to make this 2 queries as one.

Comment: This is called a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Simon Thank you for answering, is it possible left join when a column has data or null.

Comment: The left join will take all values from the LEFT (1st) table and join it to the RIGHT (2nd) table and append null where there is no data in the 2nd table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting `FROM` multiple tables performs a join of the two, and your `WHERE` clause is filtering out any resulting rows where the colors do not match, including where product_pics has no color information at all. This is equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.location), p.no, c.thumb_file
FROM product_pics AS p
INNER JOIN color_all AS c ON c.color = p.color
WHERE style_number = '$style'
ORDER BY p.sort ASC";
```

Run that query, and you should see exactly the same result as you have right now: only rows where product_pics has a color and that color is matched in color_all are returned.

What you're looking for is an `OUTER JOIN`, which does not filter out rows where one side or the other has a null value in the join column. Outer joins come in two flavors, `LEFT` and `RIGHT`. The former is most common, since generally queries are written progressing from a source table to an auxiliary table. This query should give you what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.location), p.no, c.thumb_file
FROM product_pics AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN color_all AS c ON c.color = p.color
WHERE style_number = '$style'
ORDER BY p.sort ASC";
```

Comment: Thank you !! appreciate It is exactly what I want. ^^